# Haar measure of abelian subgroup of non-abelian group

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, abelian-groups, connectedness, haar-measure

I am trying to prove non-ergodicity of a certain map, and it boils down to the following.

Suppose we have a compact connected Lie group $G$ with Haar measure $\mu$, and suppose that $G$ is non-abelian. Consider a non-empty abelian Lie subgroup of $G$, let's call it $H$. Can we conclude that $0<\mu(H)<\mu(G)$?

Apologies if this is trivial, this is quite a journey from my field which is why I am consulting the MSE experts :)

Edit: Is $H$ even Borel (or open) in the first place? The $H$ I have in mind is the group generated by some $g\in G$ which is not the identity. It is not clear to me!

Comment: $H$ can certainly have measure zero.  Consider $S^1$ as a subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Comment: H is composed of a countable collection of points in your edit. Given G is Lie, H must have measure 0.

Comment: Likewise, If H has lower manifold dimension, it has measure 0. But you need to be wary of subsets which are not manifolds but might seem to be to the casual observer. ie the image of $\{(t, \sqrt{2} t)\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any proper Lie subgroup $H$ of a connected Lie group $G$ has measure $0$.  First of all, $H$ is indeed Borel in $G$, since every compact subset of $H$ is closed in $G$ and so since $H$ is $\sigma$-compact it is $F_\sigma$ in $G$.

Now since $G$ is connected, we must have $\dim H<\dim G$.  Covering $H$ by compact coordinate charts, we then see that $H$ is a countable union of compact subsets of $G$ with empty interior, and so is meager in $G$.  Since every coset of $H$ is also meager in $G$, it follows that $H$ must have uncountable index in $G$ (otherwise $G$ would be a countable union of cosets of $H$, contradicting the Baire category theorem).  Since all the cosets of $H$ must have the same measure, this implies they must all have measure $0$ (otherwise the measure on $G$ would not be $\sigma$-finite).

(There are other arguments you can give as well; for instance, you can say that each compact coordinate chart in $H$ is a smoothly embedded submanifold of $G$ of positive codimension and so must have measure $0$ because Haar measure on $G$ has the same null sets as Lebesgue measure in any coordinate chart.)